# How to generate Read Receipt After reading the sms

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I go through this site:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android .

And developed sms app.

Now I have to make a app which has to send sms and after receive and reading the sms a Read Receipt should be generated. Do you know how to do this?